# Why does a Capitalization error work locally...?

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I've encountered this situation a couple of times now where everything is working fine locally, then when I push to remote server, I get errors due to simple Capitalization error.

`'App\Useraction'` vs `'App\UserAction`

The same error exists locally, so why does everything still work?

**Is there an Apache or PHP setting that's allowing this to work?**

I'd like to change my local environment so I can catch these..!

Using:

- Local: Mac OS / Apache 2.4.25 / PHP 7.1 / Laravel 5.4
- Remote: Linux / Apache / PHP 7.1 / Laravel 5.4

I'm not concerned with suppressing the error, correcting the capitalization is the way to go. I really would just like to know why it's able to find my class locally even though there is a capitalization error.

Comment: Is the server that it's working on being Windows and \*NIX on the other by any chance?

Comment: Or sorry I should have mentioned that. Windows is not involved.

Comment: Mac locally, Linux remote.

Comment: Both Mac and Linux are case-sensitive, should that be the case here.

Comment: I know... that's why I was thinking there's some setting "helping" me here to not error out locally.

Comment: You are probably working on a Windows WAMP server were the file system is case insensitive. Once you push it to your Linux server, you notice the error because that file system is case sensitive. Just correct the case.

Comment: *"I was thinking there's some setting "helping" me here to not error out locally."* - You could suppress the error with an `@` if that's what the question is about; unless I haven't grasped the question fully, *sorry*.

Comment: So what's the specific error you are getting then? PHP error/warning about a class file not found by the auto loading mechanism (which one)? Or is it rather related to file access on web server level? (Where stuff like MultiViews could be messing with things.)

Comment: @ jjwdesign he said he was working with MAC.. So no Windows or WAMP.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm not concerned with suppressing the error, correcting the capitalization is the way to go.  I really just want to know why it's able to find my class locally even though there is a capitalization error.

Comment: Sorry some of the above comments about case sensitivity are offbase because while the OS X file systems APFS and HFS+ are case sensitive, they are by default installed as being *NOT* case sensitive!  (try it under a terminal). So if you are using the default install of OS X you've got a chance of  ending up with discrepancies.

Comment: From googling, I found this apache module [mod_speling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html), but it doesn't appear to be enabled in my local environment.